# Scala: chaining multiple Option.when calls

Tags: scala

I have code as:

```
Option.when(condition)(evaluation)
```

..and I want to add another condition if first one fails, basically pseudo code like:

```
if(condition) {
    Some(evaluation)
} else if(another condition) {
   Some(another evaluation)
} else None
```

So what's the accepted way of chaining multiple Option.when?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Option.orElse`

```scala
Option.when(false)(1).orElse(Option.when(false)(2)).orElse(Option.when(true)(3)) // Some(3)


// that's to say
val conditions: List[Boolean] = List(false, false, true)
val values: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)

val result: Option[Int] = conditions.zip(values).map {
    case (cond, value) => Option.when(cond)(value)
  }.reduceLeft(_ orElse _) // Some(3)
```

---

UPDATE: use lazy evaluate example

```scala
val n = 7

def randomBooleans(): Iterator[Boolean] = 
  Iterator.continually(scala.util.Random.nextBoolean()).take(n)

def randomValues(): Iterator[Int] = 
  Iterator.continually(scala.util.Random.nextInt()).take(n)

val res = randomBooleans()
      .zip(randomValues())
      .foldLeft(Option.empty[Int]) {
        case (res, (cond, value)) => {
          res.orElse(if (cond) {
            println(s"${cond} ${value}")
            Some(value)
          } else {
            println(s"${cond} ${value}")
            None
          })
        }
      }

println(s"result ${res}")

// false -1035387186
// false -1516857504
// true 1775201252
// result Some(1775201252)
```

Comment: The only thing I would suggest here is to preserve the short-circuiting semantics by iterating over conditions and values lazily.

Comment: @stefanobaghino `when` and `orElse` are lazy, so you won't evaluate those unless you need them.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you commented after the code was changed, notice how the code looked before the revision. ;-)